# How to send output to both screen and mail?

Tags: io-redirection, email, output

I use the following to send an email at the end of a script.

```
echo "Script finished on `date`" | /usr/bin/Mail -s "Script complete" "myaccount@myserver.com".
```

However, I want to echo the same message onto the screen as well. How do I do that in the same statement?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to `tee` the message to stderr as well as stdout:

```shell
echo "Script finished on date" | tee /dev/stderr \
    | /usr/bin/Mail -s "Script complete" "myaccount@myserver.com"
```

`tee` duplicates its input to multiple destinations, including stdout. By default, both stderr and stdout go to the screen; you're redirecting stdout to `Mail`, leaving just stderr going to the screen.

If you need it in stdout for some reason, you could redirect it back using a subshell (or several other ways):

```shell
(
    echo "Script finished on date" | tee /dev/stderr \
        | /usr/bin/Mail -s "Script complete" "myaccount@myserver.com"
) 2>&1
```

Comment: alternatively, tee to a file and then mail the file...very useful if the output is huge and you want to send it, e.g., as a base64-encoded gzipped MIME attachment.  or just redirect all output to a file (e.g. with `exec &> $LOGFILE`) and then restore stdout, cat the file to stdout and mail it.

Comment: Thank you Craig. Since my text in this case is very small, I will go with the response from derobert.

Comment: Hmm.. this did work however I realized that I needed to add more to my problem description. I used this solution as the last line of my script. I used a "nohup" command on my script to collect all the output of my script as "nohup.out" and all I see is just this one line "Script finished on xxxxx". Prior to using this solution, I got all the script output fine. Is there a way how I can append the output of this last one line instead of erasing it all?

Comment: Using "tee -a" solved the problem.